# Boolean Logic in AND statement

Tags: c

I created a program that calculates the divisibility by 3 and 5. If divisible by 3 print 'CS' and if divisible by 5 print 'CS1714'. If divisible by both print 'CS1714'. If not divisible by 3 or 5 print 'ERROR'.

My code executes properly. However is it possible for the Boolean && to break if say both values are false. Also why does the code print 'CSERROR' when input is 98988?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int userInput;
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    
    if((userInput % 3) == 0){
        printf("CS");
    }
    if((userInput % 5) == 0){
        printf("1714");
    }
    else if(!((userInput % 5) == 0 && (userInput % 3) == 0)){
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the input is `98988` it is printing `CSERROR` because the number `98988` is divisible by 3 and that is why the first `if` condition is true and thus it prints `CS`, and then you gave another `if` where you are checking if the number is divisible by 5 or not, if the number is divisible by 5 then you print `1714`, else you print `ERROR`, as `98988` is not divisible by 5 that is why it goes to the `else` part and prints `ERROR` (The last `else` will always `true` if your second `if` is `false`. So, here is a logical error). Previously it printed `CS` and now it printed `ERROR`, combinedly you are seeing `CSERROR`.

One is need to be clear that, the `if-else` blocks structures are like below, and it started implementing from a `if` to go further until finds a true condition or `else`.

```
if(condition){

}
else if(condition){

}
else{

}
```

You should check both conditions (when the number is divisible by 3 and also divisible by 5) first, then check whether it is divisible by 3 , if not then check by 5. And finally if all are false that means it is not divisible by 3 and also not divisible by 5, so print error.

The code should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int userInput;
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    
    if(((userInput % 5) == 0 && (userInput % 3) == 0)){
        printf("CS1714");
    }
    else if((userInput % 3) == 0){
        printf("CS");
    }
    else if((userInput % 5) == 0){
        printf("1714");
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `98988`
Output: `CS`

Comment: Gotcha so branching made the code continue to error.

Comment: @DEZMO27 your first `if` is individual and the other `if-else` is combined block. Now, The last will always true if the your second `if` is false. So, there have logical error.

Comment: @SahadatHossain why so compliated?

Comment: @SahadatHossain Yeah definitely shouldn't have done that. Was trying to write at least amount of code as possible.

Comment: @0___________ not that much i think

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int userInput;
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    
    if((userInput % 3) == 0){
        printf("CS");
    }
    if((userInput % 5) == 0){
        printf("1714");
    }
    else if(((userInput % 5) != 0 && (userInput % 3) != 0)){
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```